# AWS S3 IAM Access with bucket policies

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

For an S3 bucket named `my_bucket` with the following Bucket Policy allow access to other IAM users with Admin access policy attached -

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Id": "Policy",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Statement to allow my_user",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::**********:user/my_user"
            },
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::my_bucket/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

I ran IAM policy simulations and and received the following error -

[image]

based on my reading of [Access control over view](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/access-control-overview.html) and [IAM Policies and Bucket Policies and ACLs! Oh, My!](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/iam-policies-and-bucket-policies-and-acls-oh-my-controlling-access-to-s3-resources/) since there is no explicit deny the other IAM accounts should have no problems.

Comment: Correct, this bucket policy doesn't deny any access. Other IAM principals that have policies allowing access will succeed. Is that your question? Or is it related to the failure of the simulator?

Comment: Yea. What I am trying to see if there is any documentation that would either explain how this works and/or if I can prove that using Policy Simulator ?